# Cannibals and villagers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-oceancraft

In the Minecraft Mod Oceancraft there is a new mob called cannibals. The main question that I have is can the cannibal kill the villager?

Because there is no spawn egg for the cannibal when you enter creative I can't really test it. I also don't want to run the risk of having my villagers eaten alive.

Comment: Don't worry. Once the eating starts they won't be alive for long. Problem...er, solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The answer is no.

Cannibals can't kill villagers. I tried spawning a cannibal using /summon OCCannibal and some villagers with their spawn eggs. The cannibals didn't attack the villagers, and they only attacked me in survival mode when I hurted them.